# Anime: main character falls asleep and wakes up in a different dimension with a girl

Tags: story-identification, anime, isekai

A few years back I remember watching an anime where the main character fell asleep and woke up in a different dimension.

I forget exactly what he did there but he woke up with a girl. He could only hear the girl say one word, which he then gave to the girl. Though he can't, everyone else who hears her can understand her completely.

He goes to sleep again and finds he's in that world, but this time with the girl and someone else (if I'm correct, it was the person taking care of him). This goes on for several episodes, where they fight different enemies and get about two to three other people on their side.

The last person seems to have an extremely strong connection to that specific world. It seems like that world was not just a dream but an actual thing. I forget what happens after that, but if anyone can help put a name to this I will greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds Like [Re:ZERO](https://www.crunchyroll.com/rezero-starting-life-in-another-world-). The synopsis on [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5607616/) is:

> Shortly after being summoned to a new world, Subaru Natsuki and his
> new female companion are brutally murdered. But then he awakes to find
> himself in the same alley, with the same thugs, the same girl, and the
> day begins to repeat.

But then again it does remind me of another short anime that I can't remember the name of

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you please include some details of *Re:Zero* that show how it matches the points in the question?